# How to make image draggable within the view parent in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, draggable, react-native-gesture-handler, panresponder

I have a FlatList carousel and I'm using react-native-gesture-handler to create a draggable zoom in effect for the image. The zoom in and dragging works, however I'm having problems setting a boundary for the image as it is overlapped by the next image once I zoom in and the dragging will go all the way to the end of the slider. I found a couple of examples where you can achieve this, but all of them were with react-native-reanimated. This is my code so far:

```
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
console.log("height", height, width)
const ITEM_HEIGHT = height * 0.7
const ITEM_WIDTH = height * 0.46

const Preview = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { item, goBack } = route.params;
  const buttonRef = React.useRef();
  const ref = useRef()
  const selectedPhotoIndex = data.findIndex((i) => i.id === item.id)
  const scrollX = useRef(new Animated.Value(selectedPhotoIndex)).current
  const scale = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current
  const panRef = useRef()
  const pinchRef = useRef()
  const translationX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
  const translationY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current
  const [scrollEnabled, setSCrollEnabled] = useState(true)
  const goToIndex = useCallback((info) => {
    const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    wait.then(() => {
      ref.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: info.index, animated: true });
    })
  })

  const pinchEvent = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { scale: scale } }], { useNativeDriver: true })

  const onStateChange = (event) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
      setSCrollEnabled(false)
    }
    const nScale = event.nativeEvent.scale
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.END || event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      if (nScale < 1) {
        Animated.spring(scale, {
          toValue: 1,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }).start()

        translationX.setOffset(0)
        translationY.setOffset(0)
        setSCrollEnabled(true)
      }
    } else if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
      setSCrollEnabled(false)
    }
  }

  const panEvent = Animated.event([{
    nativeEvent: {
      translationX,
      translationY
    }
  }], { useNativeDriver: true })

  const onChange = (event) => {
    translationX.extractOffset()
    translationY.extractOffset()
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {


    }
  }

 

  const RenderItem = ({ item, translateX, viewLimit }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ height, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignContent: 'center' }}>
        <PanGestureHandler failOffsetY={[-500, 500]} 
        failOffsetX={[-500, 500]} 
        enabled={!scrollEnabled} 
        ref={panRef} 
        simultaneousHandlers={[pinchRef]} 
        onHandlerStateChange={onChange} 
        onGestureEvent={panEvent}>
          <Animated.View style={{
            height, transform: [
              { translateX },
              { scale }
            ],
          }}>

            <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.image_url`}>
              <PinchGestureHandler ref={pinchRef} 
              simultaneousHandlers={[panRef]} 
              onGestureEvent={pinchEvent} 
              onHandlerStateChange={onStateChange}>
                <Animated.Image
                  source={{ uri: item.image_url }}
                  style={{
                    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
                    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
                    transform: [
                      { translateX: translationX },
                      { translateY: translationY }
                    ]

                  }}
                  resizeMode='contain'
                />
              </PinchGestureHandler>

            </SharedElement>
          </Animated.View>

        </PanGestureHandler>

        <View
          style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10, paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
        >
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', paddingLeft: 6 }}>
            <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.title`}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'white',
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  lineHeight: 28
                }}
              >
                {item.title}
              </Text>
            </SharedElement>
            <SharedElement id={`item.${item.id}.description`}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'white',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  lineHeight: 18
                }}
              >
                {item.description}
              </Text>
            </SharedElement>
          </View>
        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }

  return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#0f0f0f', overflow: 'hidden' }}>
      <BackButton navigation={navigation} />


      <Animated.FlatList
        onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }],
          { useNativeDriver: true })}
        pagingEnabled
        nestedScrollEnabled={true}
        snapToInterval={ITEM_WIDTH}
        decelerationRate="normal"
        scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
        horizontal
        ref={ref}
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        initialScrollIndex={selectedPhotoIndex}
        onScrollToIndexFailed={info => goToIndex(info)}
        renderItem={({ item: details, index }) => {
          const inputRange = [
            (index - 1) * ITEM_WIDTH,
            index * ITEM_WIDTH,
            (index + 1) * ITEM_WIDTH
          ]

          const swipeX = scrollX.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [ITEM_WIDTH, 0, -ITEM_WIDTH]
          })
          const viewLimit = translationX.interpolate({
            inputRange,
            outputRange: [ITEM_WIDTH, 0, -ITEM_WIDTH / 2]
          })
          return (

            <RenderItem viewLimit={viewLimit} translateX={swipeX} item={details} />

          )
        }} />


    </View>

  );
};
```

[image: image on zoom]

How I can zoom in and contain the image dragging within the view, without the image being overlapped by the others?I've tried to change the gesture handler based on this topic https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/110 but it didn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated!